# Add asp:textbox dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have an `aspx` page made with ASP.NET Web Forms. What i need to create is two `asp:textbox` fields. I want to be able to dynamically add two new fields below that with the press of a button.

So basically i want to be able to add an infinite amount of "new" textfields. But i'm not sure how to do this in ASP.NET.

Is there perhaps a way to create an arrat of those textfields? So that when a `form` is posted i can easily iterate over them?

How can i do this?

Comment: you can but you will need to maintain the state dynamically added control.

Comment: @krshekhar Ok, i guess that's fine? :) Sorry, i'm really new to ASP.NET, so i'm not really sure what to do with your advice :(

Comment: you can go through this link http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/435801/How-to-Add-Textbox-dynamically-using-Csharp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your aspx file:

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox1"/>
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="textbox2"/>

 <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAdd" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
 <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="ph" />
```

In your aspx.cs file:

```
 protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      TextBox tb1 = new TextBox();
      TextBox tb2 = new TextBox();
      ph.Controls.Add(tb1);
      ph.Controls.Add(tb2);
 }
```

Comment: This requires a postback... for dynamically adding new textboxes, javascript would be more user-friendly. Also you are missing an `s` on `EventArg`... And also this will not allow for infinite adding.

Comment: OP did not state that postback is not allowed. And if javascipt is turned off, what then? This solution has no dependency on javascript and requires minor modifications to achieve true infinite adding. In my opinion, this points the OP to the right direction and answers the question. :) Will update the code to add `s` Thanks @MikeSmithDev

Answer (score 0):

You can add this fields and make them hidden(invisible).
And you can show fields on button click (with javascript). 
Dynamically adding serverside controls is problem.